# I got this issue when i try to add an item to shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

This is my github https://github.com/stefanborcia/Online-Movie/tree/master
[image]
[image]

When i add an item in shopping cart one of them is working and updating as well.

But the others id add them i get this issue with iidentity_insert is set to OFF.

Comment: you should not set 'Id' in Method Add Because is identity and auto-set by SQL

Comment: Can you be more explicit, please

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the Id (in fact, it is the product Id) in the url, cause of shoppingCart.id=productId ,and the shoppingCart id is automatic, the database thinks that you want the id not to increase automatically and you want use id  to increase Manually

You can to use this code "shoppingCart.Id = 0;" to  solve problem (causes shoppingCart.Id   to increase automatically)

```
public IActionResult Details(ShoppingCart shoppingCart)
{

shoppingCart.Id = 0;
```

Comment: thank you so much ! this helped me to update/add items in shopping cart! really apreciate it

Comment: @BorciaIulianStefan,your welcome,if this question is okay,please accept my question(green flash and upvote)